# GNOME showing double top bar and search box on display

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell

Double icons in the top bar and this overlapping search box of GNOME on the front desktop.The top bar looks normal when I open any application but  getting back to the desktop, it looks like in the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of the ruined desktop]

Is there any way to reset the GNOME or any other solution to this?

Comment: What happens if you run the following command in Terminal `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems someone has changed your desktop background image to an old screenshot of your desktop.

Open **Settings** and change your desktop background.

Comment: :D Yeah! That someone would be me!!

Comment: @TakshakRajput I actually thought someone was playing a practical joke on you :-D